# Only one POST string works

Tags: javascript, php, html

What's wrong with cnid?

When i use $_POST['cnid'] in PHP it doesn't work.

$_POST['seen'] works well.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#conversation").click(function() {
      var cnid = $(this).data('id');
      $.post("messenger.php",
        { seen: "seen", cnid: "cnid" },
        function() {});

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="conversation" data-id="<?php echo $conversation['id']; ?>"></div>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['seen'])) {
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE arany_messages SET seen = 'SEEN' WHERE id = '$_POST[cnid]'");
}
```

Comment: `"cnid"` is a __string__ with value `cnid`.

Comment: Looking at your script i would say that `seen` is one that doesnt work. .. Where does it fill?

Comment: @Ingus `"seen"` is a simple string.

Comment: @u_mulder oh then he need remove "" from `cnid` in  `{ seen: "seen", cnid: "cnid" }`?

Comment: try output var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @Ingus exactly)

Comment: Seen works, i have tested it @Ingus

Comment: @u_mulder i know, but I want to use its value as $_POST

Comment: @Omar change `cnid: "cnid"` to `cnid: cnid`

Comment: Once again - `cnid` is a variable with some value, `"cnid"` is a simple string.

Comment: @u_mulder, Thank you i have solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553888/u-mulder

The Correct JS code is:

`{ seen: "seen", cnid },`

Answer (score -1):

Change `{ seen: "seen", cnid: "cnid" }` into `{ seen: "seen", cnid: cnid }`

Comment: Thank you for trying, but it doesn't work.
The correct answer is by u_milder